# Form Redirect after Submit to PHP mySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, redirect

I need to redirect submissions so that users aren't taken to a blank screen.

Here's the code for my form::

```
<form action="giveaway_execute.php" method="post">
    First Name:
    <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" name="lastname" /><br />
    etc...
    ...
    ...
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </p>
    </form>
```

and here's the php for 'giveaway_execute.php' which interacts with the mySQL db (everything submits; removed password and db name for security)::

```
<?php 

define ( 'DB_NAME','xxxx');
define ( 'DB_USER','xxxx');
define ( 'DB_PASSWORD','xxxx');
define ( 'DB_HOST','localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!link) {
die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value1 = $_POST['firstname'];
$value2 = $_POST['lastname'];
$value3 = $_POST['phone'];
$value4 = $_POST['street'];
$value5 = $_POST['city'];
$value6 = $_POST['state'];
$value7 = $_POST['zip'];
$value8 = $_POST['email'];
$value9 = $_POST['weddingdate'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO entrants (firstname, lastname, phone, street, city, state, zip, email, weddingdate) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6', '$value7', '$value8', '$value9')";


 if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

I've tried redirects on the PHP file but nothing is working. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can just `include` another page after you're done with your database operations, or as suggested you can use a `header` call but be sure to use an absolute url.

Also worth noting your code is highly vulnerable to `SQL injection`, and it doesn't do any validation.

It's a good idea to use `isset` on your fields to avoid getting notices and SQL errors if fields aren't set.

Finally, it's recommended to use a library such as `PDO` or `mysqli` over the older mysql_* extension.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on SQL (this is a first for me). Tried the header function in a variety of way that didn't work. Includes not working either. Can you give me an example of where to put either one?

Comment: It wont work if your output has already started, enable [`error reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
header('location:page2.php');
```

at the end of the file.

Replace page2.php with the actual page you want to send them to

Comment: You should use absolute urls for a location header

Comment: I guess you are right --- http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30 I always have been using relative... oops

Comment: Yeah. I've tried that and retried just now. Not working... thanks though!

Comment: what mdo you mean it isn't working? What happens? is there an error? This is a pretty standard function.. dont think there is any reason it shouldnt be working

Answer (score 0):

```
// process.php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'root');
if(isset($_POST['value'])){
  error_log(print_r($_POST,1),0);
  $db->query('INSERT INTO test (id, value) VALUES (NULL, "'.$_POST['value'].'")');
  header('Location: http://google.com');
  exit();
}
else {
  echo "$_POST is not set.";
}

// form.php
<form action="process.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="value">
  <input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Try something simpler and build from there. Also read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php